# Checking if a pair of strings are a substring of a zipped list - python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, zip, substring

```
b_list=["some data"]
s_list=["some data"]

approved_b=[list of "b_list" elements that are approved]
approved_s=[list of "s_list" elements that are approved]

br, sr=[],[]
for b,s in zip(b_list, s_list):
    if (b,s) in zip(approved_b, approved_s):
        br.append(b)
        sr.append(s)
```

The problem is this :

If you have `alpha`, it needs to recognize that `alpha` is equivalent to `alpha 1`, `alpha 100`, `zoom alpha`, etc. This can be done by `x in y`.
However, I need to be able to do it simultaneously (twice at a time) to the whole zip.

Example:

```
b_list=['alpha', 'beta time', 'gamma', 'ohm']
s_list=['gary', 'paul', 'lime', 'apple']

approved_b=['alpha 1', 'beta', 'gamma 2', 'ohm']
approved_s=['gary time', 'zoom', 'lime time', 'appler']
```

the results needs to be:

```
br=['alpha','gamma']
sr=['gary','lime']
```

So basically, when it's going through the validation, it needs to check that the `(b,s)` pair in `(b_list, s_list)` matches with `(approved_b,approved_s)` and that `b` can be substring of `approved_b` and `approved_b` can be substring of `b` **AT THE SAME TIME**, `s` can be substring of `approved_s` and `approved_s` can be substring of `s`.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking for. But if you can show us your code using `x in y` that handles just the `b` values, it should be pretty easy to show you how to change it to handle the `zip(b, s)` values.

Comment: Why does `ohm, apple` not appear in the output because `"ohm" in "ohm" and "apple" in "appler" == True`? Note: `b in approved_b and approved_b in b => b == approved_b` - I'm not sure that is what you meant.

Comment: At this point, I am thinking that "apple" in "appler" should not return true. So it should only return true if "apple"+some other stuff (like "apple SDGSD"). But either way is fine.

Comment: b= alpha, approved_b= alpha 1 So b in approved_b would return true.

Comment: But I need to check both contents of the zip. Also, I need to be able to check that approved_b in b also returns true (or not)

Comment: b_list=['alpha', 'beta time', 'gamma', 'ohm']
approved_b=['alpha 1', 'beta', 'gamma 2', 'ohm']                         s_list=['gary', 'paul', 'lime', 'apple']
approved_s=['gary time', 'zoom', 'lime time', 'appler'] b_list in approved_b should return true for all elements. s_list in approved_ s should return [true, false, true, either true or false]

Comment: @Achampion, that is what i meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having to assume a lot from your code because I'm not quite following your descriptions. It sounds like you only want to match a whole word in the `approved` lists, so you can use `in` on the `split()` of each entry, e.g.:

```
def match_pair(e1, e2, lst1, lst2):
    return any(e1 in l1.split() and e2 in l2.split() for l1, l2 in zip(lst1, lst2))

In []:
br, sr = zip(*[(b, s) for b, s in zip(b_list, s_list) 
               if match_pair(b, s, approved_b, approved_s)])
print(br)

Out[]:
('alpha', 'gamma')

In []:
print(sr)

Out[]:
('gary', 'lime')
```

In more long hand then this would be:

```
br, sr = [], []
for b, s in zip(b_list, s_list):
    if match_pair(b, s, approved_b, approved_s):
        br.append(b)
        sr.append(s)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Seems like what I am looking for. I am still messing around with the data to check if it works properly. TY!

Comment: You may want to pre-split the approved lists into word sets, as performance will be dramatically improved with a list of sets.